# Download Attachment using Sales force .NET mobile sdk

Tags: c#, salesforce, win-universal-app

I am using Sales force Mobile SDK for .NET for my Universal Windows App

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/04/salesforce-mobile-sdk-windows-ready-microsoft-developers.html

I am trying to download Attachment using following code

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get, AccountManager.GetAccount().InstanceUrl + "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Attachment/00S28000000FlXoEOK/Body");

var client = SDKManager.GlobalClientManager.GetRestClient() ??
                new RestClient(AccountManager.GetAccount().InstanceUrl);

var response = await client.SendAsync(restRequest);
```

I am getting an unknown error with no error specification.
Any help highly appreciated.

Stack trace

> at Salesforce.SDK.Rest.RestClient.d__b.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
> thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at Salesforce.SDK.Rest.RestClient.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> Sample.ViewModel.MasterViewModel.d__3c.MoveNext()

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Are you getting it from the REST service or from your code?

Comment: await client.SendAsync(restRequest); REST service, but the error has no description

Comment: Did you try Fiddler'ing the request? Perhaps the raw response could provide more detail from the API as to why the call is failing.